# Realign multiple divs into a fixed div

Tags: css, html, layout

I was tired of trying to align div boxes like the attached image below:

[image]

I've tried with the coding I have done like in this link,

[**JSBIN**](http://jsbin.com/IVUFiqi/2/edit)

How best to resolve the problem as well as adjust the layout as I want, as shown in the figure?

Any assistance is greatly appreciated, 
Thank in advance

Comment: thank you @Mr_Green have responded to my post, a warm greeting

Answer (score 0):

I have given it a quick go using JSFiddle, this is what I came up with. You should be able to use it and change it to how you would like it.

Update: [DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/rKw6Q/)

**HTML:**

```
<div class="con">
    <div class="left">
        <div class="box">Text Text Text Text</div> <span class="underbox">3 Days ago</span>

        <div class="box">Text Text Text Text</div> <span class="underbox">3 Days ago</span>

    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <div class="textwall">
            <div class="image">Image here</div>Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.con {
    width: 500px;
    height: 200px;
    border: #000000 solid 1px;
}
.left {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    border: #000000 solid 1px;
}
.right {
    float: right;
    width: 49%;
    height: 100%;
    border: #000000 solid 1px;
}
.box {
    width: 90%;
    height: 20%;
    border: #000000 solid 1px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 5px;
}
.underbox {
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.textwall {
    margin: 10px;
}
.image {
    float: left;
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    background: red;
    margin: 5px;
}
```

Comment: I think the both solution can solve the problem, I'll to try all this way, whichever is appropriate to my scheme, Thank You....

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you'd want to do, but I solved it this way:
http://jsbin.com/ebuRAFe/4/

I think the problem with your markup / css is, that you're thinking a bit too complex. All you have to do is to float your boxes appropriately and use percentage measures.

Comment: wow, it's a very solution-way, thank you @VoodooDS for the quick response, I think it really gives a good solution.
Because it is due to my understanding of about the CSS is very less.
about that, I promised to implement your suggestions.